# OpenOffice : how to load data from http address?

Tags: openoffice-basic

With an Openoffice macro, I want to load data from my local webserver. I tried this code :

```
Dim stringWeb As String, webAddr As String
Dim doc As Object
Dim opts(0) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue

webAddr = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

opts(0).Name = "Hidden"
opts(0).Value = True

doc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(webAddr, "_blank", 0, opts)
stringWeb = doc.Text.String
doc.close(True)

MsgBox(stringWeb, 0, "Result")
```

This code works, but how to do when the webserver doesn't listen on port 80 ?? (for example, on port 8080)
I tried webAddr = "http://127.0.0.1:8080" but it doesn't work :(

Someone could help me ? Thanks.

Edit: perhaps with this kind of code ?

```
Dim vParser, vDisp
Dim oUrl As New com.sun.star.util.URL
oUrl.Complete = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
vParser = createUnoService("com.sun.star.util.URLTransformer")
vParser.parseStrict(oUrl)

vDisp = StarDesktop.queryDispatch(oUrl, "", 0)
If (Not IsNull(vDisp)) Then vDisp.dispatch(oUrl, noargs())
```

But I don't know how to use it :/

Comment: Just a random guess, maybe you can drop the `scheme` (`http://`) when giving it an explicit port?  Otherwise you'll need to post the error you're getting when you use the second form.

Comment: The error is : URL seems to be an unsupported one.

Comment: (Regarding the edit): Good try, but the `URLTransformer` service will not help in this case.  I just looked into that.  The problem is not actually a URL parsing problem, despite what the error may sound like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```vb
webAddr = "http://178.33.250.62:8080/"  'portquiz.net
```

On my machine I do not have a web server running at all, so the following results in an IllegalArgumentException ("Unsupported URL"):

```vb
webAddr = "http://127.0.0.1"
```

It seems, then, that the problem is not related to OpenOffice or Basic.  Rather, the problem lies in the way your web server is configured.

Comment: mmmmm curious o_O It appears you have right . mm , let me check :P

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Apache send a PROPFIND command to the webserver (before GET). And my webserver doesn't know this command.

Headers send :

```
PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Apache OpenOffice/4.1.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Depth: 0
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 259

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop><resourcetype xmlnx="DAV:"/><IsReadOnly xmlnx="http://ucb.openoffice.org/dav/props/"/><getcontenttype xmlnx="DAV:"/><supportedlock xmlnx="DAV:"/><lockdiscovery xmlnx="DAV:"/></prop></propfind>
```